# How do I turn a JavaScript Date into a TZ string?

Tags: javascript, node.js, date

I would like to get a Date in the format below. I don't know the proper name (which has made searching quite difficult), but I call it a 'TZ string':

```
2016-01-28T20:39:17.512Z
```

I have tried:

```
> new Date("2016/02/28 00:19:58").toString()
'Sun Feb 28 2016 00:19:58 GMT+0000 (GMT)'

> new Date("2016/02/28 00:19:58").valueOf()
1456618798000
```

What's the proper name for a 'TZ string', and how can I turn a Date into one?

Answer (score 1):

Got it, it's called an **ISO 8601** date string:

```
 new Date("2016/02/28 00:19:58").toISOString()
```

See [date.toISOString() docs](https://developer.mozilla.org/en/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Date/toISOString).

Comment: So after you post your question you got the answer and framed the answer here in just 11 seconds?  wow!!

Comment: @Reddy Yep! Ended up Googling 'javascript tz format' and found `toISOString()`. https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Rubber_duck_debugging .

Comment: lol the link was new to me :D interesting ... But still I dont think this is the right place for Rubber Duck Debugging :)

Comment: @Reddy - See: [Can I answer my own question?](http://stackoverflow.com/help/self-answer) Yes! Stack Exchange has always explicitly encouraged users to answer their own questions. If you have a question that you already know the answer to, and you would like to document that knowledge in public so that others (including yourself) can find it later, it's perfectly okay to ask and answer your own question on a Stack Exchange site.

Comment: @Roberto roger that!!

Comment: You should not expect "2016/02/28 00:19:58" to be correctly parsed by any browser. It's not consistent with ISO 8601 so parsing is entirely browser dependent (including being treated as invalid).

Comment: Ack @RobG. In this case it's node, so V8 handles it, but that's an excellent point.